# Can someone explain those free 0.00000001 BTCs?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info

I've just noticed an odd transaction to my wallet address. [1LnNQDKV6DiMnZ2rZ9yXpcnnTh7my1WusP](https://blockchain.info/address/1LnNQDKV6DiMnZ2rZ9yXpcnnTh7my1WusP) seems to be giving me a free 0.00000001 BTC.

Investigating further shows that I'm not the only one receiving the free 0.00000001 BTC. [Take a look at the blockchain transaction.](https://blockchain.info/tx/cb8a8c62f3654557b6ea31c27d32e8de5bef502177c809b325f7e3a46638cc62)

What is happening? Is this guy using blockchain's public note as an advertisement spam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. This is a kind of advertisement which targets bitcoin users to spend bitcoin in a particular service. Something like an booklet which people in store are giving you when you have used their service.

But keep in mind that blockchain public note is not a function of bitcoin itself (by this I mean that you can not add it though bitcoin client). This is a service offered by blockchain.info and they just add this by attaching a field to their database. You can read more about it by reading their [FAQ](http://blockchain.info/wallet/website-faq) in the section public note.